# What are some ways to compare file type and encodings to resolve buggy grep...?

Tags: vim

In this case I have a folder of .txt files I created using *drag and copy and paste* from Adobe Acrobat PDFs and Text Editor in OSX. I've been editing these files in vim. Now I'm using grep to find notes in these files. For example,

```
grep -c "\[t\]" Herbert*
```

`[t]` is the note and the directory has 22 files with the name-prefix `Herbert*` (as in `Herbert-02-Transformation.txt`, `Herbert-14-Classification.txt`). The trouble is `grep` only finds the search string in one file (`Herbert-03-Square.txt`), but each file has the same note many times.

The trouble files display `converted` in the status bar when I open them,

```
"Herbert-02-Transformation.txt" [converted] 276L, 57171C
```

[A post at unix.stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23389/how-can-i-set-vims-default-encoding-to-utf-8) suggests special characters from the original have survived the trip from PDF to vim to cause this trouble with `grep`. I've been deleting the borked characters and manually inserting the proper `:digraphs`. Some of the edited files are searchable by grep and other edited files are not. I attempted to use,

```
:e Herbert-02-Transformation.txt
:set encoding=utf-8` 
:w
```

but the file still opens as shown above. Now I'm thinking I need to figure out how to compare the encodings of those files where `grep` is working and those where it is not. There are enough help pages detailing *how to set up file detection* in .vimrc to avoid this problem that I've spent over 1.5 hours researching this, and I now think its a good question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to pass a few lines from one of the problem files through `od`:

```
head Herbert-02-Transformation.txt | od -c
```

Or, if you see nothing strange in the first lines, look for your specific string and a few characters around it:

```
od -c Herbert-02-Transformation.txt | grep -C 5 "\["
```

For example:

```
$ echo "lorem ipsum [t] dolor sit amet" > foo.txt
$ od -c foo.txt 
0000000   l   o   r   e   m       i   p   s   u   m       [   t   ]    
0000020   d   o   l   o   r       s   i   t       a   m   e   t  \n
0000037
```

Any "weird" characters will be displayed by `od`.

---

Another useful tool is `file` which will return the file type and other information:

```
$ file --mime foo.txt 
foo.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Comment: Big mess... `\0` character is added between every character:
`0000000 376 377  \0   2  \0   .  \0      \0   O  \0   P  \0   E  \0   R`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text file of a known encoding, with invalid characters in between that do not belong to this encoding, you might be able to filter them out with `iconv -c -f charset -t charset file`. Careful not to overwrite your original file in the process as the result may be disastrous if you pick the wrong charset.

for example getting rid of umlauts:

```
$ echo Nähkästchen | iconv -c -f us-ascii -t us-ascii
Nhkstchen
```

A search&replace may be more appropriate though if those characters you have in there are in any way meaningful. Depends on what's actually in there.

Comment: +1 thanks for providing this solution. For the context of the question (and SE) I marked the above as correct.